GUI Interface for a command line program in C# Windows Forms
I am brand new to C# and this is my first time making a GUI. The program is pretty simple, since I don't have too much knowledge of GHDL. All it does is take the file paths, and generate relevant command prompt commands to then run and display the output of the command prompt to a textbox on the GUI. It also runs the VCD file in GTKWave after you've run the design.
Everything works fine (to my knowledge) and I am planning on adding more features such as run options and whatnot. I just want feedback on how I can make my code more readable and/or optimized.
Code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal;

namespace GHDL_GUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Process ps; //for running cmd.exe
        private Size formOrig; //for the form resizing
        private Rectangle button1; //same and rest
        private Rectangle button2;
        private Rectangle button3;
        private Rectangle button4;
        private Rectangle button5;
        private Rectangle button6;
        private Rectangle button7;
        private Rectangle button8;
        private Rectangle button9;
        private Rectangle button10;
        private Rectangle button11;
        private Rectangle panel1A;
        private Rectangle panel2A;
        private Rectangle label1A;
        private Rectangle tetbox1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Resize += Form1_Resiz; //resizing stuff til line 56
            formOrig = this.Size;
            button1 = new Rectangle(WorkDir.Location, WorkDir.Size);
            button2 = new Rectangle(SelPkg.Location, SelPkg.Size);
            button3 = new Rectangle(SelectDesign.Location, SelectDesign.Size);
            button4 = new Rectangle(CheckDesign.Location, CheckDesign.Size);
            button5 = new Rectangle(SelectTestbench.Location, SelectTestbench.Size);
            button6 = new Rectangle(CheckTestbench.Location, CheckTestbench.Size);
            button7 = new Rectangle(Execute.Location, Execute.Size);
            button8 = new Rectangle(HelpBtn.Location, HelpBtn.Size);
            button9 = new Rectangle(RestartDir.Location, RestartDir.Size);
            button10 = new Rectangle(GTKGo.Location, GTKGo.Size);
            button11 = new Rectangle(ClearCmd.Location, ClearCmd.Size);
            panel1A = new Rectangle(panel1.Location, panel1.Size);
            panel2A = new Rectangle(panel2.Location, panel2.Size);
            label1A = new Rectangle(label1.Location, label1.Size);
            tetbox1 = new Rectangle(CmdPrompt.Location, CmdPrompt.Size);
            SelPkg.Enabled = false; //initial conditions of buttons til 69
            SelPkg.BackColor = Color.Red;
            SelectDesign.Enabled = false;
            SelectDesign.BackColor = Color.Red;
            CheckDesign.Enabled = false;
            CheckDesign.BackColor = Color.Red;
            SelectTestbench.Enabled = false;
            SelectTestbench.BackColor = Color.Red;
            CheckTestbench.Enabled= false;
            CheckTestbench.BackColor = Color.Red;
            Execute.Enabled = false;
            Execute.BackColor = Color.Red;
            GTKGo.Enabled = false;
            GTKGo.BackColor = Color.Red;
            CmdPrompt.ReadOnly = true; //so you cant type in textbox
        }

        private void Form1_Resiz(object sender, EventArgs e) //resizing
        {
            resize_Control(WorkDir, button1);
            resize_Control(SelPkg, button2);
            resize_Control(SelectDesign, button3);
            resize_Control(CheckDesign, button4);
            resize_Control(SelectTestbench, button5);
            resize_Control(CheckTestbench, button6);
            resize_Control(Execute, button7);
            resize_Control(HelpBtn, button8);
            resize_Control(RestartDir, button9);
            resize_Control(GTKGo, button10);
            resize_Control(ClearCmd, button11);
            resize_Control(panel1, panel1A);
            resize_Control(panel2, panel2A);
            resize_Control(label1, label1A);
            resize_Control(CmdPrompt, tetbox1);
        }

        private void resize_Control(Control c,  Rectangle r) //resizing
        {
            float xRatio = (float)(this.Width) / (float)(formOrig.Width);
            float yRatio = (float)(this.Height) / (float)(formOrig.Height);
            int newX = (int)(r.X * xRatio);
            int newY = (int)(r.Y * yRatio);
            int newWidth = (int)(r.Width * xRatio);
            int newHeight = (int)(r.Height * yRatio);
            c.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
            c.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
        }

        private void ButtonEnabling(int select) //so they dont click buttons before stuff stuff selected
        {
            if (select == 0) //if they have selected reset button
            {
                WorkDir.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
                SelPkg.Enabled = false;
                SelPkg.BackColor = Color.Red;
                SelectDesign.Enabled = false;
                SelectDesign.BackColor = Color.Red;
                CheckDesign.Enabled = false;
                CheckDesign.BackColor = Color.Red;
                SelectTestbench.Enabled = false;
                SelectTestbench.BackColor = Color.Red;
                CheckTestbench.Enabled = false;
                CheckTestbench.BackColor = Color.Red;
                Execute.Enabled = false;
                Execute.BackColor = Color.Red;
                CmdPrompt.ReadOnly = true;
                GTKGo.Enabled = false;
                GTKGo.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (select == 1) //if they have selected work directory
            {
                WorkDir.BackColor = Color.Lime;
                SelPkg.Enabled= true;
                SelPkg.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
                SelectDesign.Enabled = true;
                SelectDesign.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            }
            if (select == 2) //if they select optional packages
            {
                SelPkg.BackColor = Color.Lime; //maybe this is superfluous?
                SelectDesign.Enabled = true;
                SelectDesign.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            }
            if (select == 3) //if they selected the designs
            {
                SelectDesign.BackColor = Color.Lime;
                CheckDesign.Enabled = true;
                CheckDesign.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
                SelectTestbench.Enabled = true;
                SelectTestbench.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            }
            if (select == 4) //if they selected the testbenches
            {
                SelectTestbench.BackColor = Color.Lime;
                CheckTestbench.Enabled = true;
                CheckTestbench.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
                Execute.Enabled = true;
                Execute.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            }
            if (select == 5)
            { //ran the code
                GTKGo.Enabled = true;
                GTKGo.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            }
        }

        private void HelpBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // "helpful menu" pops up
        {
            MessageBox.Show("GUIDELINES:\n1. Entity Names must match file name\n2.lmao");
        }

        private void WorkDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //when you click the directory
        {
            SelectWorkDir.Description = "Select working directory."; //description
            SelectWorkDir.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop; //default location
            SelectWorkDir.ShowNewFolderButton = false; //cant make new folders
            DialogResult result = SelectWorkDir.ShowDialog(); 
            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SelectWorkDir.SelectedPath)) //clicked ok and not empty
            {
                ButtonEnabling(1); //reference that method
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! No working directory selected!");
            }
        }

        private void SelPkg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //select packages
        {
            SelectPkgsd.Multiselect = true; //select multiple things
            SelectPkgsd.Title = "Select one or more optional Packages"; //description
            SelectPkgsd.Filter = "VHDL files (*.vhd)|*.vhd|All files (*.*)|*.*"; //file types
            DialogResult result = SelectPkgsd.ShowDialog();
            //string[] selectedPkgs = SelectPkgsd.FileNames;
            if (result == DialogResult.OK && SelectPkgsd.FileNames != null) //click ok and there is stuff
            {
                ButtonEnabling(2);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Warning! No package files selected!"); //warning since pkgs aren't necessary
                ButtonEnabling(2);
            }
        }

        private void SelectDesign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectDesignd.Multiselect = true;
            SelectDesignd.Title = "Select your design file(s)";
            SelectDesignd.Filter = "VHDL files (*.vhd)|*.vhd|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            DialogResult result = SelectDesignd.ShowDialog();
            //string[] selectedDesigns = SelectDesignd.FileNames;
            if (result == DialogResult.OK && SelectDesignd.FileNames != null)
            {
                ButtonEnabling(3);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! No Design files selected!");
            }
        }

        private void SelectTestbench_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectTestbenchd.Multiselect = false;
            SelectTestbenchd.Title = "Select your testbench";
            SelectTestbenchd.Filter = "VHDL files (*.vhd)|*.vhd|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            DialogResult result = SelectTestbenchd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK && SelectTestbenchd.FileName != null)
            {
                ButtonEnabling(4);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error! No Testbench file selected!");
            }
        }

        private string WorkingDir(string myinput)
        {
            string FullMessage = $" cd \"{myinput}\" ";
            return FullMessage;
        }

        private string PrintingA(string[] strings)
        {
            string[] StringMessage = new string[strings.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
            {
                StringMessage[i] = $" & ghdl -a --std=08 \"{strings[i]}\"";
            }
            string FullMessage = string.Join("", StringMessage);
            return FullMessage;
        }

        private string SyntaxingA(string[] strings)
        {
            string[] StringMessage = new string[strings.Length]; //new string array
            for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
            {
                StringMessage[i] = $" & ghdl -s --std=08 \"{strings[i]}\""; //concats pkg or design with syntax commands
            }
            string FullMessage = string.Join("", StringMessage); //concats everything together. Thank God this exists
            return FullMessage; //commands for syntaxing either packages or designs
        }

        private string RemoveExtension(string myinput) //removes extension to testbench can be elaborated and ran
        {
            string ffn = myinput;
            string fne = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ffn); //make sure you made the entity the same as file name or you're screwed
            return fne; //returns file name without extension. 
        }

        private string PrintingTB(int selector,string myinput)
        {
            string temp = RemoveExtension(myinput);
            if (selector == 1) 
            {
                string FullMessage = " & ghdl -a --std=08 " + Path.GetFileName(myinput) + " & ghdl -e --std=08 " + temp + " & ghdl -r --std=08 " + temp + " --vcd=" + temp + ".vcd";
                return FullMessage; //commands for running testbench
            }
            else if (selector == 2)
            {
                string FullMessage = " & ghdl -a --std=08 " + Path.GetFileName(myinput);
                return FullMessage; //commands for analyzing testbench
            }
            else
            {
                return "You Messed Up!"; //needed this
            }
        }

        private string SyntaxingTB(string myinput)
        {
            string temp = RemoveExtension(myinput);
            string FullMessage = " & ghdl -s --std=08 " + Path.GetFileName(myinput);
            return FullMessage; //commands for checking syntax of testbench
        }

        private string RunGTK(string myinput)
        {
            string temp = RemoveExtension(myinput);
            string FullMessage = " & gtkwave " + temp + ".vcd"; 
            return FullMessage; //commands for running GTKWAVE
        }

        private string MessageSelector(int selection) //this selects what the cmd arguments are
        {
            string workingDir = SelectWorkDir.SelectedPath;
            string[] selectedPkgs = SelectPkgsd.FileNames;
            string[] selectedDesigns = SelectDesignd.FileNames;
            string tb = SelectTestbenchd.FileName; //store all paths

            if (selection == 1) //if you click check design syntax
            {
                if (selectedPkgs == null) //case where there are no packages
                {
                    string commands = @"/c " + WorkingDir(workingDir) + PrintingA(selectedDesigns) + SyntaxingA(selectedDesigns);
                    return commands;
                }
                else //case where there are packages
                {
                    string commands = @"/c " + WorkingDir(workingDir) + PrintingA(selectedPkgs) + PrintingA(selectedDesigns) + SyntaxingA(selectedDesigns);
                    return commands;
                }
            }
            else if (selection == 2) //if you click check testbench syntax
            {
                if (selectedPkgs == null) //case where there are no packages
                {
                    string commands = @"/c " + WorkingDir(workingDir) + PrintingA(selectedDesigns) + PrintingTB(2,tb) + SyntaxingTB(tb);
                    return commands;
                }
                else //case where there are packages
                {
                    string commands = @"/c " + WorkingDir(workingDir) + PrintingA(selectedPkgs) + PrintingA(selectedDesigns) + PrintingTB(2,tb)+ SyntaxingTB(tb);
                    return commands;
                }
            }
            else if (selection == 3) //if you click run
            {
                if (selectedPkgs == null) //case where there are no packages
                {
                    string commands = @"/c " + WorkingDir(workingDir) + PrintingA(selectedDesigns) + PrintingTB(1,tb);
                    return commands;
                }
                else //case where there are packages
                {
                    string commands = @"/c " + WorkingDir(workingDir) + PrintingA(selectedPkgs) + PrintingA(selectedDesigns) + PrintingTB(1,tb);
                    return commands;
                }
            }
            else if (selection == 4) //if you click OpenGTKWave
            {
                string commands = @"/c " + WorkingDir(workingDir) + RunGTK(tb); //This is needed because when you click Open, the command process closes and you need to cd back into working directory
                return commands; //arguments for running GTKWave
            }
            else
            {
                return "You Messed Up!"; //lol
            }
        }
        
        private void CheckDesign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunCMD(1); //Checks the design
        }

        private void CheckTestbench_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunCMD(2); //checks the testbench
        }

        private void Execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunCMD(3); //runs the testbench
            ButtonEnabling(5); //allows you to click OpenGTKWave
        }

        private void RunCMD(int selector)
        {
            if(ps != null && !ps.HasExited) //if process is open
            {
                ps.Kill(); //close it
                ps.Close();
            }
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(); //start info
            psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"; //the program
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true; //so cmd window doesn't pop up
            psi.UseShellExecute = false; //I read that this was a good thing to have
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //allows output to go somewhere else
            if (selector == 1)
            {
                psi.Arguments = MessageSelector(1); //reference this method
            }
            else if (selector == 2)
            {
                psi.Arguments = MessageSelector(2); //reference this method
            }
            else if (selector == 3)
            {
                psi.Arguments = MessageSelector(3); //reference this method
            }
            else if (selector == 4)
            {
                psi.Arguments= MessageSelector(4); //reference this method
            }
            ps = Process.Start(psi); //starts the process
            string strBuffer = ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //make a new string for your cmd output
            foreach (var substring in SelectPkgsd.FileNames) //look below
            {
                strBuffer = strBuffer.Replace(substring, ""); //This is so if you use a function from a package in a different directory, it doesn't spit the path at you.
            }
            if (strBuffer == "" && selector == 1) //since GHDL tells you literally nothing when your syntax is right, I added this.
            {
                CmdPrompt.Text = "No syntax errors in design files"; //Tells you your design is free of syntax errors
            }
            else if (strBuffer == "" && selector == 2) //same as line 409 comment
            {
                CmdPrompt.Text = "No syntax errors in testbench file"; //Tells you your testbench is free of syntax errors
            }
            else
            {
                CmdPrompt.Text = strBuffer; //Puts the output of the command prompt to this box. Pretty neat.
            }
        }

        private void GTKGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunCMD(4); //reference this method
        }

        private void RestartDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonEnabling(0); //resets everything so you can't click buttons
        }
    }
}

Here is what the GUI looks like:


I don't know why the image description won't show up, but I know the clear button does nothing under the textbox. I will remove that later.

Welcome to Code Review! From the markdown help for images: “The word in square brackets is the alt text, which gets displayed if the browser can't show the image. Be sure to include meaningful alt text for screen-reading software.” so it might only appear in a tooltip on mouse over.

meaningful names
These are not terrific identifiers.
        private Rectangle button1;
        private Rectangle button2;
        private Rectangle button3;
        private Rectangle button4;
        private Rectangle button5;
        private Rectangle button6;
        private Rectangle button7;
        private Rectangle button8;
        private Rectangle button9;
        private Rectangle button10;
        private Rectangle button11;

Prefer names like buttonWorkDir, buttonSelectPackage,
buttonSelectDesign, and so on.
meaningful comments
    ... //resizing stuff til line 56

Avoid making line number references in that way,
as {insert, delete} in the first few dozen lines
will inevitably make that comment meaningless.
A technique you might want to use is (1.) git push
to GitHub, and then (2.) grab a SHA1-specific URL with
a line number reference.
For example the URL
https://github.com/space-wizards/space-station-14/blob/bc68ac96/Content.Tools/Map.cs#L68
lets you focus on a stream assignment, and since it's a
frozen snapshot it won't ever bit rot or become an invalid reference.
enum
                ButtonEnabling(2);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Warning! No package files selected!"); //warning since pkgs aren't necessary
                ButtonEnabling(2);
            ...
            RunCMD(3); //runs the testbench
            ButtonEnabling(5); //allows you to click OpenGTKWave
            ...
            ButtonEnabling(0); //resets everything so you can't click buttons

Rather than
magic
small integers, the buttons and commands should rely on
Enum
values. Then you wouldn't need so many comments to explain what
some cryptic integer means.
Also, you could conditionally warn and then unconditionally
enable button 2.

Thank you for your feedback. I agree with the identifiers for the rectangles. I did that super fast because I was frustrated by the resizing and just wanted to apply a fix.
Enums are a great idea, I will find a way to implement that.
For your final point, would something like this what you had in mind?
ButtonEnabling(2);
if(you didn't select stuff or clicked cancel)
{
MessageBox.Show("Warning Message");
}

Overall, thank you for your feedback.

All those buttons and initialisation should be in the designer file, which allows the WYSIWYG designer to help with designing the form, buttons, etc.
The resizing of controls should also be controlled by the designer, along with docking and parenting of controls that are attached to the edges of other controls, such that when you drag the right hand border, controls will automatically resize as appropriate, without all those complicated ratios.
RemoveExtension basically exchanges a 1 line method that is called in many places, and replaces it with a 3 line method that is called in many places.
